# Ubuntu budgie freezing

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, freeze, ubuntu-budgie

I'm new to linux. I'm trying to install Ubuntu budgie on my laptop and unfortunately it freezes randomly after a few minutes into it.

I'm coming from a completely clean format of an SSD and I'm trying to dual boot along windows 10 entreprise LTSB. I'm running UEFI-CSM type of bios, in GPT partition style. I managed to install windows without issues and it's running fine.

After that, I wanted to install ubuntu budgie 17.10.1 so I shrunk the NTFS partition windows was installed on to about half its size. Set up a swap of 4096MB and formatted the rest to ext4 to install ubuntu on. I did all of this in Gparted within the ubuntu installer.

This is when the issues started. While I was doing my things in Gparted, my laptop suddenly froze, leaving my mouse and keyboard unresponsive. Eventually, it rebooted by itself without my intervention. I tried again, and this time managed to complete the installation. Linux booted correctly and all was good. However within 5 minutes, same issue again: freeze and reboot. I tried again, and it froze and rebooted again.

At that point, I had my BIOS configured in strict UEFI and I figured this could be a problem for some reasons. So I changed it to UEFI-CSM and re-installed Ubuntu cleanly again. But I'm still getting the same issues both during and after the install...
This is my hardware: http://prntscr.com/ij3lun

Any help is much appreciated.